# any way of making encodeURIComponent in javascript ignore certain characters?

Tags: javascript

is there any way I can make the `encodeURIComponent`  method ignore certain characters for example if I don't want it to encode the `£` sign. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible without wrapping it yourself.

Probably the safest thing to do would be...not do this. If you're a thrill seeker, just undo the parts you want decoded after the encoding is complete.

Something like this might be a naive way (i.e. my way) of doing it:

```
encodeURIComponent(uri).replace('%A3','£')
```

Comment: Agreed. Just use `string.replace('%C2%A3','£');`

Comment: I swear that code sample wasn't there when I posted my comment... maybe I am going blind.

Comment: Your method wouldn't perform a global replace, it would only replace the first occurrence of `£`.  For a global replace `/%C2%A3/g` would be required for the first parameter.

Comment: @Josh: Michael might have put it in during the 5 minute silent editing window.

Comment: @Andy Huh, never knew about that!

Comment: certainly would work in a way but not the best code practice. the reason i was asking about this is that i'm trying to unescape a string in ruby that was encoded by the encodeURIComponent(uri), but it recognizes '%C2%A3'  as a    '?'.