# JavaScript - Encode characters and URI malformed error

Tags: javascript, encode

I recently have a bug, when I try to send into my node server a query search of the following:
!@#$%^&*()_+ 
I get an error on my Chrome:

```
{status: 500, message: "URI malformed"}
message: "URI malformed"
status: 500
```

After reading:
[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) 
[Javascript decodeURI(Component) malformed uri exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064536/javascript-decodeuricomponent-malformed-uri-exception) 
[any way of making encodeURIComponent in javascript ignore certain characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858574/any-way-of-making-encodeuricomponent-in-javascript-ignore-certain-characters) 
[Percent encoding javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911820/percent-encoding-javascript) 
[Pass a percent (%) sign in a url and get exact value of it using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342671/pass-a-percent-sign-in-a-url-and-get-exact-value-of-it-using-php) 
[Javascript decodeURI(Component) malformed uri exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064536/javascript-decodeuricomponent-malformed-uri-exception)

My code still won't work for: !@#$%^&*()_+ when I wrap my string with encodeURIComponent and in the server do decodeURIComponent. 
It also does not work with encodeURL. 
If I do manually replace I get %2525 and it's not good.
Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks.

My code:

```
const endpoint = `${endpoint}&text=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;
await fetch(endpoint);
```

Comment: tha't might be a double-encoding problem. `%2525` happens when you first encode the percent sign `%` => `%25`, and then re-encode that: `%25` => `%2525`. It's better explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249900/extra-escape-character-in-go-url

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet that builds the URL and launches the request? You should use `encodeURIComponent`, but probably you are doings something wrong in that process.

Comment: That code doesn't give me the chrome error.

Comment: What is `endpoint`? What is `query`? And how do you apply `decodeURIComponent` in the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually there was a bug on my server side. I tried to decode the '%' sign.
Solved it by the following:

On the client:

```
const endpoint = `${endpoint}&text=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;
await fetch(endpoint);
```

On the server:

```
decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(query.text))
```

Comment: That's rather pointless. Just use `query.text` directly.

Comment: @bergi I edited the code. If you have other way to pass '!@#$%^&*()_+' to the server from the client I would be happy to hear.

Comment: As I said, just directly use `query.text` on the server.

Comment: @bergi but then I will get an error if I will try to send '#' or '&' to the server.

Comment: No you won't. If you would, you'd also be getting the error when getting `query.text` and applying the pointless `decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(…))` to it.